# Adding a xib to a framework

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard, xib, xcode-storyboard

I have a project I'm working in and I'm attempting to add some files from a sandbox app I created into the project. Everything works fine except adding a xib. The xib is "there" in the project navigator, but when I look at Target Membership, there is no target selected even though I selected it when dragging the file over. I see the target in the list of targets under Target Membership, but the target I want will not let me tick the box.

Additionally, I created a xib within the destination project and I still get the same issue where I can see the target listed, but I can't tick it.

Has anyone ever seen this issue and is there a simple way around it?

I'm running Xcode 12.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to go into build phases and add the file in question manually. Not sure why it didn't happen automatically, but it works and that's all I care about.